# PL/pgSQL loop produces unexpected "too many range table entries" error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to update a partitioned PostgreSQL table using a PL/pgsql loop to restrict the update to looking at one partition at a time, because it contains a self join on a large table. I keep getting the error "too many range table entries", and I don't understand why. If I hardcode the partition to update in the WHERE clauses, it works just fine, even if I run 10 partitions at the same time using IN ().

I thought those two practically did the same thing; looping over the UPDATE for each value for city_id in turn. Is that wrong? How can I get it to do that?

This doesn't work:

```sql
DO
$$
DECLARE
    ele record;
BEGIN
    FOR ele IN SELECT city_id 
           FROM dwh.city
    LOOP 
        UPDATE dwh.residence res1
        SET residence_count = res2.residence_count
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                block_id, 
                COUNT(*) as residence_count,
            FROM dwh.residence  
            WHERE 1=1
                AND city_id = ele.city_id
            GROUP BY block_id
        ) res2
        WHERE 1=1
            AND res1.city_id = ele.city_id
            AND res1.block_id = res2.block_id;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

But, this does work:

```sql
UPDATE dwh.residence res1
SET residence_count = res2.residence_count
FROM (
    SELECT 
        block_id, 
        COUNT(*) as residence_count,
   FROM dwh.residence  
   WHERE 1=1
       AND city_id = 1
  GROUP BY block_id
) res2
WHERE 1=1
    AND res1.city_id = 1
    AND res1.block_id = res2.block_id;
```

Comment: You get that error if too many tables are involved in a single statement. Remember that all partitions are tables. You self-join a partitioned tables, which increases the number of range tables. Restricting to a partition at planning time reduces the count, and the statement can succeed.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing by adding the partitioning column (city_id) in the WHERE clause. The partitions are in the form dwh.residence_cityname though, so I suppose it would work as intended if I rewrite it as dynamic sql to add the city name?

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment posted by @LaurenzAlbe, using dynamic SQL to refer to table partitions individually solves the error (I broke out the variables because I thought it looks clearer this way):

```sql
DO
$$
DECLARE
    var_city_id int;
    var_city_name varchar;
BEGIN
    FOR var_city_id, var_city_name IN 
        SELECT city_id, city_name
        FROM dwh.city
    LOOP 
        EXECUTE
            'UPDATE dwh.residence_' || var_city_name || ' res1
            SET residence_count = res2.residence_count
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    block_id, 
                    COUNT(*) as residence_count,
                FROM dwh.residence_' || var_city_name || '
                WHERE 1=1
                    AND city_id = ' || var_city_id || '
                GROUP BY block_id
            ) res2
            WHERE 1=1
                AND res1.city_id = ' || var_city_id || '
                AND res1.block_id = res2.block_id;';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```